# Test Coverage Help- SOQL Query

Tags: soql, unit-test, query, failing-tests

I am having difficulty testing a SOQL query. I am not allowed to put hard coded data in the test. So far my test coverage is very basic but should cover a lot, it looks like:

```
static testMethod void pullthereport(){
    sendToWebService2 ctrl = new sendToWebService2(new ApexPages.StandardController(new Credit_Review__c()));
    ctrl.pullReport();
    System.assert(true); 
}
```

pullReport() runs bvsUpdate(). bvsUpdate() runs serializeData(). serializeData() is erroring out at the SOQL query. **Without putting hard coded data in, how am I able to get oppId to not be null?** I assume this is the problem. I feel like this is super easy and I will probably kick myself as soon as I post this. But any help is appreciated!

The error I am getting is: **System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your currentPgId is retrieved from the url parameter and your controller extension is initialized with a dummy unpersisted data. So you need to create a solid - inserted into database - Credit_Review__c record and use that to initialize your extension class. And aside from it, use Test.setCurrentPage() to set the parameter.

Below is the sample code:

```
Credit_Review__c cr = new Credit_Review__c();
//... data set up code goes here
insert cr;
Pagereference pr = Page.YOURPAGENAME;
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id', cr.Id);
sendToWebService2 ctrl = new sendToWebService2(new ApexPages.StandardController(cr));
```

Aside from it, `System.assert(true);` is evil. You should never be using it.